# sapnwrfc call always returns None/NULL

Tags: python, saprfc, pyrfc

I know that the newest library to connect python and SAP is [PyRFC](http://sap.github.io/PyRFC/), I am using Windows to develop a django app and when I try to install the `pyrfc-1.9.3-py2.7-win32.egg` that is what corresponds to my system, It gives me error while importing the library, the error is shown because the modules that pyrfc imports are missing, I followed the whole README doc but I have no idea how to use this library.

I decided to use [sapnwrfc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sapnwrfc/) instead, so I downloaded the source and compile it with MinGW, it installed pretty well and I can now establish a connection with SAP, but there are errors calling an RFC function.

This is my code

```
def results(request):

    sapnwrfc.base.config_location = BASE_DIR+'\\sap.yml'
    sapnwrfc.base.load_config()

    try:
        conn = sapnwrfc.base.rfc_connect()
        fd = conn.discover("ZRFC_TEST_TODO")
        f = fd.create_function_call()
        f.QUERY_TABLE("IT_SUCS") # ERROR IN THIS LINE
        f.ROWCOUNT(50)
        f.OPTIONS=([{'BUKRS': "TVN"}])
        f.invoke()

        d = f.DATA
        todo = {'results': d}

        conn.close()

    except sapnwrfc.RFCCommunicationError as e:
        todo = {'error':e}
    return render_to_response(json.dumps(todo), content_type='application/json')
```

The error is

> NoneType object is not callable

and if I change it to

```
f.QUERY_TABLE="IT_SUCS"
f.ROWCOUNT=50
f.OPTIONS=[{'BUKRS': "TVN"}]
f.invoke()
```

then the error disappears BUT `f` is always null.

I need to get some tables from an RFC from SAP, any idea to solve this? Is there another way to do it? maybe another library?

**UPDATE**
After testing and debugging I think that the `fd` variable is not initialized correctly, because when I try to see `fd` attributes, python stops and error is shown:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: you'd better install pyrfc rather than reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

A bit late...

```
def get_table():
    QUERY_TABLE = 'MY_TABLE'
    Fields = ['MY_FIELD']
    FIELDS=[{'FIELDNAME':x} for x in Fields]
    get_data = conn.call("RFC_READ_TABLE", DELIMITER='|', FIELDS=FIELDS, QUERY_TABLE=QUERY_TABLE, )
    get_data = get_data['something in get_data']
    # here format your data, for x in ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the line:

f.OPTIONS=[{'BUKRS': "TVN"}]

these parameter is line a line to append on SELECT execution.
so it's like:

f.OPTIONS=[{ "BUKRS = 'TVN'" }]

Att.

Comment: it is the same thing, same result = null :(